Updating array object in React reducer state
I am trying to update a "story" that is in an array stored in state.
How it is working:

User submits form with edits
Function updateStory runs - which posts update to API (saves in database)
Dispatches the same "Edited Story" to reducer case "story/updated"
this is where I receive error: state.stories.map is not a function

My function saves the changes to an API (which works) but fails to update the state array. I receive the error:
state.stories.map is not a function
TypeError: state.stories.map is not a function

It is my understanding that I should map the array and update the item that needs to be updated. But the function doesn't see my state.stories.map as a function. (Is it not seeing my state as an array?)
Note: I am also not sure if I can access action.payload variables the way I have (if not, I haven't discovered that error, as my code hasn't gotten that far).
The Stories Struct is this:

The payload is this:

My reducers are set up like this:
const initialState = {
  stories: [],
  isLoading: false,
  currentStory: {},
  error: "",
};


function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "loading":
      return { ...state, isLoading: true, error: "" };

    case "stories/loaded":
      return { ...state, isLoading: false, stories: action.payload, error: "" };

    case "story/loaded":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        currentStory: action.payload,
        error: "",
      };

    case "story/created":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        //stories: [...state.stories, action.payload],
        currentStory: action.payload,
        error: "",
      };

    case "story/updated":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        stories: [
          state.stories.map((story) =>
            story.StoryID === action.payload.StoryID
              ? {
                  ...state.stories,
                  StartDate: action.payload.StartDate,
                  EndDate: action.payload.EndDate,
                  StoryTitle: action.payload.StoryTitle,
                  StoryText: action.payload.StoryText,
                }
              : story
          ),
        ],
        currentStory: action.payload,
      };
// etc.

Function:
function StoriesProvider({ children }) {
  const { user } = useAuth();
  const [{ stories, isLoading, currentStory, error }, dispatch] = useReducer(
    reducer,
    initialState
  );

async function updateStory(theStory, StoryID) {
    dispatch({ type: "loading" });
    try {
      const res = await fetch(
        `${BASE_URL}/stories/${StoryID}/${user.UserInfo[0].CustUUID}`,
        {
          method: "PUT",
          body: JSON.stringify(theStory),
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        }
      );

      dispatch({ type: "story/updated", payload: theStory });
    } catch {
      dispatch({
        type: "rejected",
        payload: "There was an error updating story data.",
      });
    }
  }


state.stories.map returns a new array reference, so returning the new array within another array is likely incorrect. That said, where exactly is the issue you are seeing in the code you have shared? Is it the state.stories.map in the "story/updated" reducer case, or is it elsewhere? What is the value of state.stories when you are trying to iterate it as an array? Did some previous action change the type invariant of state.stories? Please [edit] to provide better details and a complete [mcve].

@DrewReese  - Yes - the error is attached to state.stories.map which happens in the reducer case "story/updated".  Will edit to show Stories state and Edited Story...

The "stories/loaded" action is the only other action I see that modifies the state.stories value. Can/have you verified what that action is updating the state to?

@DrewReese screenshot now included from the console > Components...

state.stories appears to be an object with a Stories property that is an array, i.e. the mapping would be state.stories.Stories.map(.....), or you need to save the Stories value into state.stories somewhere so it's not nested. What is the "Stories Struct" screenshot of, just the reducer state?

Thanks - I didn't catch that. (Sorry, new at React - on the edge of my knowledge and experience)
How do I match the mapped id to the payload ID?  Now that it maps, it doesn't know what the storyID is... (Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'storyID'))   Its the story.Stories.storyID that it is not able to read.
stories: [ state.stories.Stories.map((story) =>
story.Stories.storyID === action.payload.storyID
? {
...state.stories.Stories... etc

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
